# Match everything but Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Been searching for a long time, reading up about negative/positive outlook but can't get this to match everything but my regular expression.

> \b[A-Z]{1}\d{3,6}[A-Z0-9]+

is the string I **don't** want to extract.

> (?!\b[A-Z]{1}\d{3,6}[A-Z0-9]+).*

[is my best attempt using Negative Outlook](https://regexr.com/49h4m), but it will still match the data.

---

I am using this Regex on:

> 11/02/2019 1 475.50 453.345 Serial number : C580A0453WD7996 
>   AFJ_LowGuard_NewNew
>   End User Details:

---

The output I want is:

> 11/02/2019 1 475.50 453.345 Serial number :
>   AFJ_LowGuard_NewNew
>   End User Details:

Comment: Where are you using the regex? Some text editor?

Comment: Could you do a Regex replace? Like match the string you don't want and replace it with empty string and return the result.

Comment: https://regexr.com/49h4m

Comment: The software I am using only lets you 'replace' a Regex expression - therefore, I want to extract the 'Serial Number', by removing everything but that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use your regex to match and replace the match with empty string, that's one approach.

Another approach that you seem to be trying is, you can use this following regex to match anything but your regex,

```
\b(?:(?![A-Z]\d{3,6}[A-Z0-9]+).)+\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DF1AsB/1)**

This will match anything except your pattern. But personally I suggest replacing by matching your pattern should be easy.

**Edit:**

Ok I read your comment that you want to replace anything except the string matched by your pattern. In that case you can use following regex to match everything except your pattern and replace it with empty string to get your result,

```
\b(?:(?![A-Z]\d{3,6}[A-Z0-9]+).)+
```

**[Demo with replacement with empty string](https://regex101.com/r/DF1AsB/2/)**

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect - I agree, matching the pattern and replacing it makes a lot more sense. However, the software that I'm using doesn't allow for that!

Comment: @MattFalconer: I've edited my answer, where you can use the regex to replace everything else with empty string, where resultant will be the string as described by your pattern in your post. Hope that works better for you. Let me know if I can be of any further help to you.